# squirrelmail installed, but no send / receive email

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp, dovecot

I recently installed squirrelmail on Ubuntu 18.04 server mostly following the guidelines in [How to setup a mail server on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://www.osradar.com/how-to-setup-a-mail-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

I am able to use login from browser, but when trying to send mail, I get in `/var/lob/mail.log`:

```
Mar 15 12:37:00 papa-legba postfix/smtpd[26002]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 15 12:37:00 papa-legba postfix/smtpd[26002]: 8861A580AD5: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Mar 15 12:37:00 papa-legba postfix/cleanup[26005]: 8861A580AD5: message-id=<89c993abb422be17972fe0e2ac369c0a.squirrel@192.168.0.198>
Mar 15 12:37:00 papa-legba postfix/qmgr[24391]: 8861A580AD5: from=<papa-legba@papa-legba.ddns.net>, size=759, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 15 12:37:00 papa-legba postfix/smtpd[26002]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Mar 15 12:37:00 papa-legba postfix/local[26007]: 8861A580AD5: to=<papa-legba@papa-legba.ddns.net>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar 15 12:37:00 papa-legba postfix/qmgr[24391]: 8861A580AD5: removed
Mar 15 12:37:00 papa-legba dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mail_user>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=26010, secured, session=<jYDRT+eg6tl/AAAB>
Mar 15 12:37:00 papa-legba dovecot: imap(mail_user): Logged out in=651 out=589
Mar 15 12:37:00 papa-legba dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<mail_user>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=26012, secured, session=<qxHST+eg7Nl/AAAB>
Mar 15 12:37:00 papa-legba dovecot: imap(mail_user): Logged out in=117 out=1502
```

I am a bit confused even as to what the email associated with the `mail_user` account should be as I set in `squirrelmail/config/conf.pl` the domain to be `papa-legba.ddns.net`. I did open  port for smtp.

Comment: Can you tell us what steps in the howto you skipped or didn't follow?  From the log it looks as if the mail was "sent", that is, delivered locally.  Could it be that postfix considers your server as being papa-legba.ddns.net?

Comment: Only change from the steps is that I had to copy the content of `squirrelmail` to `/var/local/` and change permissions on `/var/local/squirrelmail/data/` for the browser to allow login.
How could I see postfix settings ? I did not change any of it when intalling

Comment: Also I arbitrarily  choose this `papa-legba.ddns.net` when setting up squirrelmail but it isn't really registered in dynip. Should the domain I choose be registered somewhere...?

Comment: What is the FQDN of your server, more precisely, what does postfix think its FQDN is?   If you send a message to someone at that FQDN, it stays on your server, in someone's mailbox.

Comment: Here is content of my conf.pl file -> Server Settings
```SquirrelMail Configuration : Read: config.php (1.4.0)
---------------------------------------------------------
Server Settings

General
-------
1.  Domain                 : papa-legba.com
2.  Invert Time            : false
3.  Sendmail or SMTP       : SMTP

A.  Update IMAP Settings   : localhost:143 (other)
B.  Update SMTP Settings   : localhost:25
```

Comment: I am sending an email to my own @hotmail.com account

Comment: Your log says you are sending mail "to=<papa-legba@papa-legba.ddns.net>".   Who am I to believe?

Comment: Also, are you sure your problem is with squirrelmail, and not with dovecot?